# Why i got A value of type "'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from the function 'items' because it has a return type of 'List<Item>'"

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dynamic

When i try to run this code, it is throwing me the error. I understand that my return type is mismatching but i don't know what should i do to correct it.
I tried to convert my return type to string but still the problem persists. If i turn my return type to nullable then also the problem doesn't vanished. i am new to this language and still trying to understand, so please help. :)

This is my Code-

```
import 'package:flutter_catalog/models/catalog.dart';

class CartModel {
  static final cartModel = CartModel._internal();

  CartModel._internal();

  factory CartModel() => cartModel;

  //Catalog field
  CatalogModel? _catalog;

  //Collection of IDs - store IDs of each item
  final List<int> _itemIds = [];

  //Get Catalog
  CatalogModel? get catalog => _catalog;

  set Catalog(CatalogModel newCatalog) {
    _catalog = newCatalog;
  }

  //Get item in the cart
  List<Item> get items => _itemIds.map((id) => _catalog?.getById(id)).toList();

  //Get total price
  num get totalPrice =>
      items.fold(0, (total, current) => current.price! + total);

  //Add Item
  void add(Item item) {
    _itemIds.add(item.id!.toInt());
  }

  //Remove Item
  void remove(Item item) {
    _itemIds.remove(item.id);
  }
}
```

here is the refernce for Item class-

```
class CatalogModel {
  static final catModel = CatalogModel._internal();

  CatalogModel._internal();

  factory CatalogModel() => catModel;

  static List<Item> items = [];

  //Get item by ID
  getById(int id) =>
      items.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id, orElse: null);

  //Get Item by Position
  Item getByPosition(int pos) => items[pos];
}

class Item {
  final int? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? desc;
  final num? price;
  final String? color;
  final String? image;

  Item({this.id, this.name, this.desc, this.price, this.color, this.image});

  factory Item.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Item(
      id: map["id"],
      name: map["name"],
      desc: map["desc"],
      price: map["price"],
      color: map["color"],
      image: map["image"],
    );
  }
}
```

Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'text'.
Receiver: "iPhone 12 Pro"
Tried calling: text)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuddM.png)

Can anyone specify where i was going wrong?

Comment: What line of code specifically is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that `CatalogModel.getById` doesn't have a declared return type, so it's inferred to be dynamic. Declare a return type to fix that:

```dart
//Get item by ID
Item? getById(int id) =>
    items.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.id == id);
```

Note: In the above code I'm using the first-party [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) for the `firstWhereOrNull` extension method.

Then you have the issue that `CatalogModel.getById` returns an `Item?`, and you need to construct a list of `Item`. The correct way to handle this depends on your application: is it expected that some ids won't resolve to items and so null results can just be ignored, or is that unexpected so an error should be thrown instead? A cart with items sounds more like the second case to me, so here's code for it:

```dart
//Get item in the cart
List<Item> get items => _itemIds.map((id) => _catalog!.getById(id)!).toList();
```

After that it should compile. Always provide return types for your functions.